# Errors while Ubuntu touch Port for Yureka "tomato"

Tags: compiling

i am working since last 9 months for port/compilation to be succeed. Yureka has Official cyanogenmod Rom.
Passed many errors, but now i am stuck here

```
device/yu/tomato/charger/charger.c:49:25: fatal error: minui/minui.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wsign-promo’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
host C: libsepol <= external/libsepol/src/avtab.c
build/core/binary.mk:512: recipe for target '/home/sheikh/touch/phablet/out/target/product/tomato/obj/EXECUTABLES/charger_mmx_intermediates/charger.o' failed
```

what i have

```
ubuntu system 14.10 64bit
Ubuntu touch phablet-4.4.2_r1 source code (with .repo folder 15GB)
android_kernel_yu_msm8916-cm-11.0
android_device_yu_tomato-cm-11.0
android_device_qcom_common-cm-11.0
```

if someone can tell me which file is supposed to be in `vendorsetup.sh` (lunch menu)
i added...

`add_lunch_combo full_tomato-userdebug` (is this right file to be here ? )

and compilation started (with doubt :D )

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_yu_tomato
sources for Yureka are for 4.4.4 kitkat based cyanogenmod

but Ubuntu touch sources are like phablet-4.4.2_r1 !

repo init -u https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/p/aosp/platform/manifest.git -b phablet-4.4.2_r1

Comment: misunderstanding brother :p i am not making an android rom based on cyanogen, i am making cyanogen based UBUNTU TOUCH rom.... following this guide https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/

Comment: You should still make an xda page for your rom, that site will be the best place to get help with development questions, but this can stay open.

Comment: i think You are right :)